# Make host IPv6 only and assign its sole public IPv4 to LXC container

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization, lxc

I have a Debian 10 server which gets its IPv4-v6 via DHCP which can be configured as static also:

```
root@host:~# ifconfig
ens3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 45.76.XX.XX  netmask 255.255.254.0  broadcast 45.76.XX.255
        inet6 2001:19f0:XXXX:XXX:XXXX:XXX:XXXX:XXXX  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::5400:2ff:fecf:999b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 56:00:XX:XX:XX:XX  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 113  bytes 14499 (14.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 114  bytes 12413 (12.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 24  bytes 1896 (1.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 24  bytes 1896 (1.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I know how to configure nat-ed LXC instances with private IPv4 address. But in this fresh system I wish to create a LXC instance assigning it the main public IPv4 address of the host. Is it even possible? I can SSH into host using its IPv6 when its IPv4 is taken away from it and assigned to the container.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: Please get used to `ip addr` for managing network interfaces on Linux... it's not because 'ifconfig' and 'route' are merely old, it's because they can outright lie to you -- e.g. 'ifconfig' doesn't know that an interface can have more than one IPv4 address, and 'route' doesn't know that a route can have more than one gateway. (In your case, a very useful feature would be having an IPv4 default route with an IPv6 nexthop, which is also not understood by those tools.)

Comment: @user1686 Thanks :) Force of habit. Trying to change it.

Comment: If you perhaps have to use a specific MAC address, I recommend ipvlan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easily possible if your LXC networking is using a layer-2 mode such as bridge or macvlan. That puts the container's namespace on the same layer-2 network as the host, and you can do the rest in the most obvious way: remove the IP address from the host and add it to the container. (If the address has to be assigned using DHCP, then the container can just run a DHCP client.)

(This however requires the *container's* MAC address or DHCP Client ID to be known by the local network's DHCP server. If this is a problem then you might need to assign the host a custom MAC address, and give the container the host's MAC.)

For example, if you want to use bridge mode, first create a standard Linux bridge – in this example named `br0` – with your Ethernet interface as a member. Making it permanent is very distro-dependent (using ifcfg or /etc/network/interfaces or systemd-networkd), but *temporary* configuration can be done using:

```
ip link add br0 type bridge
ip link set br0 up
ip link set ens3 master br0
```

Note: If you only have remote access to the host server, then it's a very good idea to **use KVM or serial console** when making such changes.

Then your LXC configuration might look like this:

```
lxc.net.1.type = veth
lxc.net.1.flags = up
lxc.net.1.link = br0
lxc.net.1.hwaddr = 02:00:xx:yy:zz:tt
```

If static IP configuration is wanted:

```
lxc.net.1.ipv4.address = 45.76.XX.XX/23
lxc.net.1.ipv4.gateway = 45.76.YY.YY
lxc.net.1.ipv6.address = 2001:19f0:X:X:X:X:X:X/64
lxc.net.1.ipv6.gateway = 2001:19f0:X:X::1
```

If you want to use DHCP and/or SLAAC, then just leave out the address/gateway settings and install a standard DHCP client on the container.

Once you start the container, `ip link ls master br0` and `bridge link` will show a second bridge port.

Note: I've heard claims that macvlan mode provides better performance, but I don't actually know how to configure it. Plus, it seems to require the host to *also* use a macvlan in order to be able to communicate with its own guests.

If you must use a routed mode, it's still doable in mostly the same way, but the container will *not* be able to use DHCP, and the host will additionally need to run Proxy-ARP to pretend that the IP address is still "on link" despite it being assigned to another system. (Routers don't forward ARP requests.) If DHCP is mandatory, then a special DHCP client configuration might be necessary for the host to acquire the address without actually assigning it to an interface.

Comment: Thanks @user1686 for your reply. Can you please provide the steps/code/pseudo-code for achieving this using layer-2 mode on this fresh system. Nothing has been changed/installed yet.

Comment: Those steps really helped. Thank you so much.

Comment: The static configuration for the container is working fine. But when I leave that IP/gateway lines commented out. DHCP isn't pulling any IPv4 address inside the container. My hosts's /etc/network/interfaces file in like this:

`
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#allow-hotplug ens3
#iface ens3 inet dhcp
#iface ens3 inet6 auto


auto br0
iface br0 inet manual
        bridge_ports ens3
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
`

Comment: Which DHCP client are you using inside the container? Is it running? Does it get stuck after sending out the "DHCPDISCOVER" or does it report a different problem? And is the local DHCP _server_ managed by you or is it managed by a hosting company? (My first guess is that the problem is related to the container having its own MAC address, and that might need arrangement with the network admin.)

Comment: I did not install any DHCP server specifically inside the guest OS. It came along with the debian 9 guest template (isc-dhcp-client 4.3.5-3+deb9u1). Guest OS's interfaces file is: 

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

DHCP server is of host (Vultr). Also please note that I have: "iface br0 inet manual" in the host's interfaces file so that it doesn't pull an IPv4 for itself.

Comment: Then it's very likely that you'll need to give the container the host's MAC address (by setting `.hwaddr =` in LXC), and give the host bridge a custom MAC address (e.g. by setting `hwaddress ether 56:8F:4B:65:71:D8`). But still, do check the DHCP client's logs (they should be in the container's /var/log at least). Also, does the container successfully get IPv6 in this case?

Comment: Hi @user1686 Both host and guest were getting IPv6 connectivity just fine with the above setup also. Now I changed the br0's mac address in /etc/network/interfaces on host and changed the container's mac address to that of ens3 in host (though ens3 still gets listed in ifconfig output on host with the same mac address that I supplied to guest.). The host got a different IPv6 this time which I used to SSH-in. Container isn't able IPv4 still. Does get a IPv6 though.

Comment: Listening on LPF/eth0/56:00:xx:xx:xx:xx
Sending on   LPF/eth0/56:00:xx:xx:xx:xx
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.

Comment: Sorry but the container does get a IPv6 after this change. Just no IPv4 still.

Comment: Container is getting a IPv6 but its able to ping6 google after these MAC address changes. ( Destination unreachable: Address unreachable). Container's IPv6 connectivity isn't of much importance for me though.